# php database tables access to admin and users

Tags: php

I'm looking for some kind of answer to my question where I have some tables in a database and number of users but each user should only view/access a particular table or a rows in database. its a kind of giving and denying access to user based on criteria. I'm using php are there any examples?

Comment: Search for role based access mechanism in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the simplest and probably most pathetic way which is using [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-query.php) with granting permissions queries due to [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).

looks like this:

```
$grantPermission = "GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON **your_db**.**your_table_name** TO ";
$grantPermission .= **mysql_user**;
$grantPermission .= " @'%' IDENTIFIED BY '". **mysql_password** . "'";

$result = mysql_query($grantPermission) or die("Something bad happened");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the 'Mysql Administrator' to manage restrictions for specific users and give them specific schema privileges.

You can chose to give a user a very specific list of actions he can perform in each schema and table.

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/administrator/

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer but I am more likely looking to block access to the login users